How to find a chunk of string that starts with $PATTERN and ends with $LINEBREAK
I am trying to remove a chunk of text from 100s of files. The amount of lines to remove is not the same for each one, but they do all start with the same string. I am looking to remove the entire chunk of text from $PATTERN ## Table, then select ALL of the text until a line break occurs. I am pretty "ok" with sed but not getting anywhere with Googling.
text.txt contents:
Random text.

## Table of Contents
*   [Design System](#<b>Design-System</b>)
*   [Multisite Designs](#Multisite)
    *   [Recommended Changes Per Site](#mcetoc_123)
    *   [Recommended Consistent Elements Across Sites](#mcetoc_456)
*   [Templates v. Pages](#Templates-v-Pages)
*   [Layouts](#mcetoc_dfghj)
*   [Features](#Features)
    *   [Something](#mcetoc_khjvfsdfsd)
    *   [Feature](#mcetoc_dfwyduegwu)
    *   [See More Logic](#mcetoc_fdsfsdugfs)
*   [Advertising, and Print](#Advertising-and-Print)
*   [Images](#Images)
    *   [Featured Image)](#mcetoc_fghjk) 
*   [Videos](#Videos)
    *   [Video Art](#mcetoc_4567890)
*   [Author and Search Pages](#Author-Tag-and-Search-Pages)
*   [Accessibility](#Accessibility)

Then here is some text.

Here is more text!

## Prerequisites

text.txt desired outcome:
Random text.


Then here is some text.

Here is more text!

## Prerequisites

I don't care about cleaning up extra line breaks, just deleting the chunk starting with ## Table and ending with the first line break.

I had no idea where to even begin, so I posted here. The first answer I got resulted in:
sed -e '/^\s*[*#]/d'
Random text.

    *   [Recommended Changes Per Site](#mcetoc_123)
    *   [Recommended Consistent Elements Across Sites](#mcetoc_456)
    *   [Something](#mcetoc_khjvfsdfsd)
    *   [Feature](#mcetoc_dfwyduegwu)
    *   [See More Logic](#mcetoc_fdsfsdugfs)
    *   [Featured Image)](#mcetoc_fghjk)
    *   [Video Art](#mcetoc_4567890)

Then here is some text.

Here is more text!


awk '/^## Table/ {skip=1} NF==0 {skip=0} !skip' worked as well as sed -i '' '/## Table/,/^$/d', and resulted in:
Random text.


Then here is some text.

Here is more text!

## Prerequisites


consider updating the question with some of your sed attempts and the (wrong) results

Since the patterns are mutually exclusive, you can use an address range:
sed '/## Table/,/^$/d' infile >outfile

Or, if your definition of "linebreak" includes whitespace:
sed '/## Table/,/^[[:space:]]*$/d' infile >outfile

Many versions of sed support non-standard pseudo-in-place editing with a -i option.

I was going to give an answer which retained a blank line but uncovered inconsistent behaviour between implementations. For GNU or BSD: sed '/## Table/,/^$/{g;//d;}'. For busybox: sed '/## Table/,^$/{//!d;g;}'. I have sent a report about busybox handling of range regex which seems wrong to me.

sed is great for doing s/old/new/ on individual lines but for anything else, just use awk, e.g. using any awk:
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/^## Table/' test.txt
Random text.

Then here is some text.

Here is more text!

## Prerequisites


That's the solution I was about to propose; the only downside is that you loose track of the number of blanks lines but OP's said it doesn't matter, so +1

What about awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '/^## Table/{printf "\n"; next} 1' test.txt so the trailing blank line is not lost?

@dawg I assume you meant to write '^/^## Table/.... That would add a blank line if ## Table came first in the input and would still delete blank lines if there were 2 before it, between other blocks, etc. If the OP really wanted to preserve multiple blank lines I'd just do awk '/^## Table/{f=1} !NF{f=0} !f' or similar but I suspect they're happy not having multiple contiguous blank lines.

One awk idea:
awk '
/^## Table/ { skip = 1 }             # if line starts with '## Table' then enable/set skip flag
NF==0       { skip = 0 }             # if empty/blank line then disable/clear skip flag
!skip                                # if skip flag not set (ie, skip == 0) then print current line
' test.txt

#######
# or as a one-liner

awk '/^## Table/ {skip=1} NF==0 {skip=0} !skip' test.txt

This generates:
Random text.


Then here is some text.

Here is more text!

## Prerequisites


For awk flavors that support ranges:
awk '
/^## Table/,NF==0 {next}     # if current line falls within the range of lines defined
                             # by "^## Table" and a blank line then skip it else ...

1                            # print current line
' test.txt

#######
# or as a one-liner

awk '/^## Table/,NF==0 {next} 1' test.txt

This generates:
Random text.

Then here is some text.

Here is more text!

## Prerequisites

NOTES:

this removes the matching blank line whereas OP's expected output shows the blank line is to be maintained
if OP wishes to keep the blank line then one option would be to replace {next} with {if (NF!=0) next}


Regarding "For awk flavors that support ranges:" - they all support ranges but IMO a flag like in your first script is always better, see is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '/## Table/{:a;N;/^$/M!ba;d}' file

Which will remove all lines in the range, or:
sed '/## Table/{:a;N;/^$/M!ba;z}' file

Which will remove all lines except the last newline.
Other perhaps easier though potentially wrong (this will delete every line following the start of the range even if the end of the range does not exist):
sed '/## Table/,/^$/d' file

Or
sed '/## Table/,/^$/!b;/./d' file


no idea which of the manysed commands you found you have tried, but...
what is the actual pattern for you matching strings?
for simplicity, i assume it's the start of the line, followed by an arbitrary amount of whitespace, followed by an asterisk or a hash.
this would be a regular expression ^\s*[*#]
So we build a sed-expression that deletes all lines matching this pattern:
sed -e '/^\s*[*#]/d' test.txt


Sorry, I should have been more specific. Anything with # will be removed. I need it to be more specific to "## Table"

If your files do not have any NUL byte inside then you might exploit -z option of GNU sed following way, let text.txt content be
Random text.

## Table of Contents
*   [Design System](#<b>Design-System</b>)
*   [Multisite Designs](#Multisite)
    *   [Recommended Changes Per Site](#mcetoc_123)
    *   [Recommended Consistent Elements Across Sites](#mcetoc_456)
*   [Templates v. Pages](#Templates-v-Pages)
*   [Layouts](#mcetoc_dfghj)
*   [Features](#Features)
    *   [Something](#mcetoc_khjvfsdfsd)
    *   [Feature](#mcetoc_dfwyduegwu)
    *   [See More Logic](#mcetoc_fdsfsdugfs)
*   [Advertising, and Print](#Advertising-and-Print)
*   [Images](#Images)
    *   [Featured Image)](#mcetoc_fghjk) 
*   [Videos](#Videos)
    *   [Video Art](#mcetoc_4567890)
*   [Author and Search Pages](#Author-Tag-and-Search-Pages)
*   [Accessibility](#Accessibility)

Then here is some text.

Here is more text!

## Prerequisites

then
sed -z 's/## Table[^\n]*\n\([^\n][^\n]*\n\)*//' text.txt

gives output
Random text.


Then here is some text.

Here is more text!

## Prerequisites

Explanation: I use -z which prompts GNU sed to treat NUL byte as separating lines, if there is not such byte in file then it is treated as one giant line. Then I remove ## Table followed by zero-or-more non-newline characters followed by non-newline character and trailing (0 or more) at least 1 non-newline characters followed by newline characters, that is non-empty lines (line understand as newline-separated entity).
(tested in GNU sed 4.8)

Perl is unmatched with multiline replacements:
perl -0777 -lpe 's/^## Table [\s\S]*?(?=^\s*$)//gm' file.txt

And Ruby supports that same approach:
ruby -0777 -lpe 'gsub(/^## Table [\s\S]*?(?=^\s*$)/,"")' file.txt

With the OP example input, both print:
Random text.


Then here is some text.

Here is more text!

## Prerequisites


Doesn't [\s\S] mean "a space or a non-space" which is just "any character", the same as .?

. does not match new line characters without the s flag. The construct [\s\S] matches any / all without flags.

Thanks for the info. I suppose leaving . as "any character" like in BREs and EREs and introducing \N or something for "any character except newline" if they really felt the need to abbreviate [^\n] would have just been a crazy idea to the PCRE creators, sigh.

just use 1 action-implicit pattern with awk :
awk '_ = /^## Table/ < (_^NF || NR == !_)'


# gawk profile, created Tue Nov 26 20:05:51 2024

# Rule(s)

  26  _ = /^## Table/ < (_^NF || NR == !_) { # 8
   8        print
      }


 1  Random text.
 2  
 3  
 4  Then here is some text.
 5  
 6  Here is more text!
 7  
 8  ## Prerequisites

_^NF is a combo short-hand for "either skip flag is currently false, or line is blank".
Instead of a skip flag, the state is tracked by a "keep" flag that leverages these exponentiation properties :

1^anything := 1
+
0^0 := 1

